# Find the smallest possible value for: $a+b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a,b$ are positive integers with $a, b > 1$, and

$$\sqrt{a\sqrt{a\sqrt{a}}}=b,$$

find the smallest possible value for $a+b$.

Answer (score 6):

As $a$ gets bigger so does $b$, so it suffices to find the smallest possible $a$.

The left hand side is just $a^{7/8}$. The smallest integer $a > 1$ for which this is an integer is $2^8 = 256$. Then $b = 128$ and you get $a+b = 384$.

Answer (score 1):

We have: $a^7 = b^8 \to a = b\cdot b^{\frac{1}{7}}$. Take $c = b^{\frac{1}{7}} \to a = c^7\cdot c = c^8, b = c^7$. Thus: $a+b = c^7+c^8$. Clearly the minimum occurs if $c = 2$, for $a = 2^8 = 256, b = 2^7 = 128$.

Answer (score 0):

The expression you gave is equivalent to $a^7=b^8$. Let $a=b^{\frac{8}{7}}$ and substitute this into $a+b$ to arrive at $b+b^{\frac{8}{7}}$ Now you can apply basic calculus.